# How to partially redact email address with fixed number of asterisks using regex?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that can redact the characters between first and last letters in the name (part before @) and first and the last letters in the domain (part after @) to 3 asterisks ***?

Examples:

1. `thisisatestemail@domain.com` is redacted to `t***l@d***m`?
2. `foo@bar.com` is redacted to `f***o@b***m`
3. `fo@bar.com` is redacted to `f***o@b***m`
4. `f@bar.com` is redacted to `***@b***m`

Thanks!

Comment: Something like this: `echo 'thisisatestemail@domain.com' | sed -r 's/^(.).*(.@.).*(.)/\1\2\3/g'`?

Comment: Sorry, the stars have been removed by markup in the question, I have corrected the question to reflect the right expected result.

Comment: Well, then `echo 'thisisatestemail@domain.com' | sed -r 's/^(.).*(.@.).*(.)/\1***\2***\3/g'`

Comment: Thank you so much! That almost answers the question, except, there is one edge case for `f@email.com` it's doing nothing, is there something we can do to your regex to handle this also?

Comment: And what result is expected in this case? `f@e***m`?

Comment: If so, I think safest and easiest way would be to split replacement in two steps: `sed -r 's/^(.).*(.@)/\1***\2/g;s/(@.).*(.$)/\1***\2/g'`

Comment: The expected result for `a@gmail.com` is `***@g***m`

Comment: @markalex Can you also answer my another similar question if possible please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75751784/how-to-partially-redact-phone-number-in-string-with-asterisks-using-regex ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
^(.?(?!@)).*?((?<!^).)?@(.(?!$))?.*?((?<!@).?)$
```

with replacement string `\1***\2@\3***\4`

Example:

#### Bash

```bash
echo 'foo@bar.com' | perl -pe 's/^(.?(?!@)).*?((?<!^).)?@(.(?!$))?.*?((?<!@).?)$/\1***\2@\3***\4/g'
```

#### Python

```py
re.sub(r'^(.?(?!@)).*?((?<!^).)?@(.(?!$))?.*?((?<!@).?)$', r'\1***\2@\3***\4', 'foo@bar.com')
```

**Caution:** GNU `sed` doesn't support lookaround, so wouldn't be suitable for this task.

Explanation of expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/nKfCz5/1).

Answer (score 1):

Matches of the following regular expression may be replaced by `'***'`. I've written it in *free-spacing* mode by setting the `x` flag. I've used 'lc' in the comments as an abbreviation of 'lowercase'.

```
  ^               # match start of string
  [a-z]           # match a lc letter
  (?=@)           # positive lookahead asserts match  preceds '@'
|                 # or
  (?<=^[a-z])     # positive lookbehind asserts match is preceded by
                  # the start of string followed by a lc letter
  [a-z]*          # match 0+ lc letters
  (?=[a-z]@)      # positive lookahead asserts match is followed by a
                  # lc letter at the end of the string
|                 # or
  (?<=@[a-z])     # negative lookbehind asserts match is preceded by '@'
                  # followed by a lc letter
  [a-z]+\.[a-z]+  # match 1+ lc letters, a period, 1+ lc letters
  (?=[a-z]$)      # positive lookahead asserts match is followed by a lc
                  # letter at the end of string
```

[PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/IPx4L0/1)

We can remove the comments and whitespace to obtain the expression as it is more commonly written (without the `x` flag).

```
  ^[a-z](?=@)|(?<=^[a-z])[a-z]*(?=[a-z]@)|(?<=@[a-z])[a-z]+\.[a-z]+(?=[a-z]$)
```